# C++ Adding libcurl (using Curl)? - My attempts explained

Tags: c++, curl, command, libcurl, codeblocks

Okay, so I know this sounds like a very nooby question but I did my best so please hear me out before adding negative comments/downvoting.


Okay, so from what my research says, using "cURL" for my C++ program when involving anything web-related is the best way to go. Now, me being new to C++, I didnt want to ask questions for every step and try doing it myself, apparently, this was not the case.

**Problem:** CodeBlocks is not recognizing the curl plugin (saying it does not exist)


**Goal:**

Attempt to make the example source located [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html) (from the official cURL website) work.


**Attempt 1:**
So, I downloaded the plugin using the "help manager" where it shows which is the best thing to download. I got the .zip file "*curl-7.24.0-devel-mingw32*" back. I decided to copy the contents of the "bin" folder to my projects bin and copy the "include" folder to my project. It kept saying it did not recognize "/curl/curl.h" or saying it did not exist.


**Attempt 2:**

Without deleting the "bin" and "include" folder, i decided to move the "curl.h" folder into my project itself (via CodeBlocks) by creating a folder called "curl" and then putting the "curl.h" inside the folder (The folder "curl" was in the "Headers" folder created by the program) and attempt to run it again seeing that it existed. Same Error


**Attempt 3:**

After countless searches, I come across that I should put my curl files and all the files inside the "bin" folder into C:\Windows\ folder. So I copied everything in the "includes" folder and the contents of the bin folder (including the "curl" folder in it) to the WINDOWS folder. Same error.


**Attempt 4: - Sort of...**
Now, there was something about going to my project options and selecting certain files to import and that stuff but it was way more confusing because each site had different options so im unable to do recall the steps.


Im now relying on the StackOverFlow community to give me a hand. I tried explaining my problem in the most detailed way but if you have any questions or need more information, dont hesitate to ask. Also, here is the errors im getting: 
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=B1wsqvmA


Here is my source:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YShFZf8G


Can someone please guide me through this mess? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you're not telling codeblocks where to search for the include files, you shouldn't be copying the headers to the project's folder.

You can select the include directories this way:

In Project -> Build Options -> Search Directories -> Compiler

There is a button to add include directories, in this case the "include" folder of libcURL, And that error should be gone.

You will have to follow a similar process to add the files for the linker.

Comment: I did it, just one last thing. Im trying to download a file from the internet, most sources include the curl/types.h which seems to be no longer shipped. What can i do? I tried using the sample.c from the curls website and keep getting this error: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=SiZEu7g6, here is my code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WzzKS3ET

Comment: ok, the proccess is similar, in "Project -> Build Options -> Search Directories -> Linker" you can add the "lib" folder of libcURL. Then you should add the libraries there (the *.a files) to "Project -> Build Options -> Linker Settings". The project should compile then, to run it you can copy the .dll files in the "bin" folder to your project's folder.